# Data style property to Jinja2 "invalid syntax"

Tags: flask, jinja2

I am trying to convert a bootstrap multiple selector into Jinja2, but whenever I add `data-style` property to the form field `badges = SelectMultipleField('Categorii proiect', choices=[(1, 'January'), (2,'February')])` I get invalid syntax.

**Bootstrap multiple selector**

```
<select multiple class="form-control selectpicker" data-style="btn btn-link" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
    <option>January</option>
    <option>February</option>
</select>
```

**Jinja2 template that works**

```
{{ form.badges(class="form-control selectpicker", id="exampleFormControlSelect2") }}
```

**Jinja2 template that fails**

```
{{ form.badges(class="form-control selectpicker", data-style="btn btn-link", id="exampleFormControlSelect2") }}
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because `data-style` is not a valid parameter's name (there's `-` dash character) passed to the function.

a valid name has to be Alphanumeric, `_` the underscore character is allowed, `-`, `@`, `#`  .. are not allowed

to counter the `invalid syntax` error you need to pass that parameter and any extra parameters (if any) through the `**kwrgs` object like

```
{{ form.badges(class="form-control selectpicker", id="exampleFormControlSelect2", **{"data-style":"btn btn-link" }) }}
```

Comment: Awesome, didn't know that. Thanks

Comment: @newbie99 yes it's tricky and i learnt it the hard way when i needed to pass some extra parameters in `email` field with `WTForms` without custom widget / field nor any 3rd package, have a look at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61374885/12368419 on other topic it may be useful for you.